# Can't resolve type `zbar_image_t`

Tags: c++, zbar

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zbar.h>

class BarcodeManager {
private:
    int32_t verbose;
    zbar_image_t *img;
};
```

`zbar_image_t` defined in `zbar.h` as below:

```
struct zbar_image_s;
/** opaque image object. */
typedef struct zbar_image_s zbar_image_t;
```

I included the header file zbar.h, and `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` in CMakeLists.txt .

ZBar is an open source software suite, and i download at https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/archive/0.10.tar.gz

CLion reminds me

> Can't resolve type `zbar_image_t`

And error when I `make`

> error: ‘zbar_image_t’ does not name a type

I turn on verbose options with `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` in CMakeLists.txt, and saw `-I/home/kgbook/koala -I/home/kgbook/koala/include`.

koala is a C++ project.

It seems that all header file included normally.

Comment: well, it's picking up *A* zbar.h file, but maybe the wrong one?   click on the name in clion and command-b it (or whatever on non-mac) does it take you to the right file?  did you maybe make your own zbar.h file?

Comment: after comment `#include <zbar.h>`, still `error: ‘zbar_image_t’ does not name a type`.

Comment: when I use command + single click `#include <zbar.h>` in CLion, the path of `bar.h` is `koala/include/zbar.h`, actually it's right.

Comment: I didn't write my own zbar.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved myself.

I analysis the `zbar.h`, and found it.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

/** C++ namespace for library interfaces */
namespace zbar {
    extern "C" {
#endif
```

koala project use C++, so `using namespace zba;` before using.